# Render XAML tree to an image and save it using FileSavePicker

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I'm working on WinRT app and for some reason, I want to save XAML tree as image using FileSavePicker. Currently I'm saving the image inside ApplicationData which is quite hectic to browse to afterwards. What I want is, user picks directory of their own choice and name and save the image. I'm using following code right now :

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(MainGrid);
        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Image.png", creationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

        using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, 96d, 96d,
                pixelBuffer.ToArray());

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(MainGrid);
var file = await DestinationFileFromUserAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
            (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
            (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, 96d, 96d,
            pixelBuffer.ToArray());

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    } 
}

private async Task<StorageFile> DestinationFileFromUserAsync()
{
    if (EnsureUnsnapped())
    {
        StorageFile file = null;
        FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Images", new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"});
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Image";

        file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        return file;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

internal bool EnsureUnsnapped()
{
    // FilePicker APIs will not work if the application is in a snapped state.
    // If an app wants to show a FilePicker while snapped, it must attempt to unsnap first
    return ((ApplicationView.Value != ApplicationViewState.Snapped) || ApplicationView.TryUnsnap());
}
```

Don't forget to check out [`FileSavePicker` class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207871?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. I will try it soon and let you know.